# Performance gap between write(int b) and write(byte b[]) in Java

Tags: java, linux, tcp, system-calls, serversocket

I find that, when I use `Socket socket = new Socket(); OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();` and invoke write method, there are two choices: write(int b) and write(byte b[])， and I write code to test the performance of them. I found that write(byte b[]) is faster than write(int b).
I read the source code and guess the difference maybe lead by the cost of applying a buffer and release the buffer.
But I am not sure I find the right answer because it may because the **system call** and the mechanism of **TCP/IP**.

I tried to coding to test and read the source code, I guess it may because the using of `char BUF[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];`. I tried to apply space b.length times in java every time write(bytes[] b) is invoked and compare the differences of the two method, the result is the performance gap seems not so big.

Comment: Wrap it with a `BufferedOutputStream`, you don't want to care about whether you're writing one or more bytes.

Comment: Yes, sure. However, I still want to know the underlying mechanisms between them.

Answer (score 0):

This totally makes sense.
Say you need to write 1000 bytes to the socket.

```
byte[] b = new byte[1000];
```

Doing a for-loop on **b** and writing to the stream one by one will leave you looping inside the "JVM" thus "suffering" from the JVM performance.

But, calling directly to the **write (b)** method will trigger the underlying native socketWrite0 which will use a native way to write the buffer directly to the socket file descriptor which obviously not in the JVM and is natively faster.

Comment: In my opinion, write(int b) is also invoke write(int[] bytes) and finally invoke native socketWrite0. I am not sure if my understanding is right.